# Post a blob using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Is it possible to post a blob using Guzzle?  The only methods I've been able to find are using @filename to upload a local file.  The file is stored as a blob in a MySQL database and I would like to upload it to an api as a post field without the redundancy of saving the blob to disk (and the permissions/path issues that come with it), uploading @filename, and then unlinking the file.  Here is the code I have that is working for everything but the blob.  I need the 'file' field to save the data as a blob.

```
$data = array(
    'first_name' => $fname,
    'last_name' => $lname,
    'email' => $email,
    'partner_key' => 'qwerty',
    'secret_key' => 'qwerty',
    'file' => $fileblob
);

$curl = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
return $curl->post('https://www.api.com',['verify'=>false,'body'=>$data])
```

The goal being to replace the existing cURL code using Guzzle:

```
'file' => "@".$localfile.";type=".mime_content_type($localfile)
```

Comment: Pull the data into variable and send it? Where's the problem? Either you're not explaining it very well, or I'm dumb as they come.

Comment: Curl loads the file from a localfile and Guzzle does the same, but I want to send it as a blob so avoid the steps of saving it to disk etc.  There is something missing in the above code because the api is not receiving the file in the file field.  So instead of 'file' => $fileblob it needs to be something else, I just don't know what.

Comment: I see what confuses you. Using the above code, your file will be in `$_POST['file']` instead of `$_FILES`.

Comment: ^ because curl does magic to convert @filename to post data--I need to replace that magic somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.  Hopefully this helps others in the future:

```
$data = array(
    'first_name' => $fname,
    'last_name' => $lname,
    'email' => $email,
    'partner_key' => 'qwerty',
    'secret_key' => 'qwerty',
    'file' => new \GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile('filename', $fileblob)
);

$curl = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
return $curl->post('https://www.api.com',['verify'=>false,'body'=>$data])
```

Comment: Update: if you are using Guzzle 6+ then PostFile has been depreciated and removed, so you need to use multipart which allows a blob pretty easily.  The above works for Guzzle 5.*